# How to get the name of the Flask blueprint inside a template?

Tags: python, flask

I have a site built with Flask. It has several sections, each with a dedicated blueprint. The templates in each blueprint extend a base template, which has the basic layout for each page, including a navigation bar with tabs for each section.

I'd like to have the base template highlight the current tab, so it needs to know which blueprint's view is handling the request.

One way I came up with to do this is to add a `before_request` handler to each blueprint and store the name in `g`:

```py
bp = Blueprint('blog', __name__, url_prefix='/blog')

@bp.before_request
def set_bp_name():
    g.section = 'blog'
```

But Flask must know which blueprint is handling a request (if any) and the blueprint, of course, knows its own name. Is there a way for the template to fetch the current blueprint's name that doesn't require modifying each blueprint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Quite simply: `request.blueprint`.

The `request` object is [one of a few](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-context) (along with `g`) that Flask makes available to all templates. It contains the [`blueprint`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.blueprint) property, which is the name of the blueprint handling the current request.